# How do you retrieve the current time on a server?

Tags: linux, date-time

I want to know the time on a server accurate to the millisecond.

there's this way:

```
local $ ssh user@servername
Welcome to server!
server $ date
Fri Feb 18 11:27:50 EST 2011
```

But I need more accuracy. Is there a command that will be more precise?

Comment: Network latency alone will prohibit true millisecond accuracy.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Check " man date ". You can let it display you the hours, minutes, seconds and nanoseconds with

```
date +%H:%M:%S.%N
```

See the output of

```
while : ; do date +%H:%M:%S.%N ; done
```

interrupt the infinite while loop with CTRL+C .

If you want less decimal places you could do

```
while : ; do date +%H:%M:%S.%N | cut -c 1-12 ; done
```

Increase or decrease the output length changing the "12" on "-c 1-12" after cut.

Answer (score 0):

No commands that I am aware of, but you can call [gettimeofday](http://linux.die.net/man/3/gettimeofday) to get results accurate to the millisecond. There are [compilable examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588307/c-obtaining-milliseconds-time-on-linux-clock-doesnt-seem-to-work-properly) on StackOverflow, CTT's in particular would be of interest.